# htaccess for multiple optional parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My mission is to achieve

`http://localhost/projectname/media/video`

from

`http://localhost/projectname/index.php?m=media&cmd=video`

and also

`http://localhost/projectname/home`

`http://localhost/projectname/index.php?m=home`

Below the files helps to achieve my mission

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /projectname/index.php?m=$1 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /projectname/index.php?m=$1&cmd=$2
```

the thing is that any external files such as javascript and css would not be taken into play.

i know my alternative is to put this is htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/cmd/([^/]*)$ /projectname/index.php?m=$1&cmd=$2
```

which enables `http://localhost/projectname/media/cmd/video`

I would like to make it without the CMD. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rules to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ projectname/index.php?m=$1&cmd=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ projectname/index.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And make sure your js, css, images files are using absolute path not the relative ones. Which means their paths should either start with `http://` or `/`.

Comment: thanks yours definitely solve the thing that i wanted. so whenever there is more parameters, i need to rewrite teh condition and new rules?

Comment: Yes that's correct, just make sure every RewriteRule is ending with `L` flag.

Answer (score 1):

why not just pass everything to index.php and then handle/parse the path, e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Then use

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php